# IPython 3.0 on Emacs 24.4 - how to export just code snippet; how to launch it with Python 3 instead of 2

Tags: python, ipython, osx-yosemite, emacs24

I'm using IPython 3.0.0 with Emacs 24.4 on Mac OS 10.10.2. I have both Python 2.7 and 3.4 installed. I'm using Emacs' built in python.el, not python-mode.el. As my understanding is that with Emacs 24.4, IPython integration is pretty much built in out of the box with python.el, all I've added to my Emacs init file for IPython is:
(setq
 python-shell-interpreter "/usr/local/bin/ipython"
 )

1. When I launch IPython, it's always starts with Python 2.7. 
   I tried adding to my init file:

(setenv "PYTHONPATH" "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages:")

but trying to launch IPython gives the error:

Your PYTHONPATH points to a site-packages dir for Python 3.x but you are running Python 2.x! 
PYTHONPATH is currently: "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages"
You should unset PYTHONPATH to fix this.

How can I get IPython to launch with Python 3.4?

2. If I remove the PYTHONPATH code, IPython launches with C-c C-p, but trying to launch it while a Python buffer is open with C-c ! gives 'C-c ! is undefined'.
   I can send all the code from a Python file to IPython using C-c C-c, but trying to send only a code snippet using C-c | gives 'C-c | is undefined.'

How do you send just a code snippet to IPython for interpretation?

Thanks in advance for any help that can be offered.

Comment: If `/usr/local/bin/ipython` was installed with Python 2, that's what it will start with. If you install it with Python 3, it should run with Python 3.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I installed from bash with pip install ipython.

Comment: There's a similar situation with `pip` - if it runs on Python 2, it will install packages on Python 2. So then it's a question of how you installed pip.